# ESRI map , zoom value

Tags: c#, dictionary, arcgis, esri

I would like to know how to obtain zoom value.

I have a method similar to this one and I need to send a zoom parameter obtained in my mapView.

```
 public double ownZoom(double i, double zoom){
      return i / zoom;
 }
```